# I need help adding data from an external javascript file to a textbox when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have functions built in an external js file and I am trying to create a button that will run that function and then insert the result into a textbox.

HTML Code:

```
<label for="fName">First Name </label>
            <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" /><p>
            <input type="button" value="JS Test" name="button1" onclick="writeHumanName(this.form)" />
```

JS Code:

```js
function writeHumanName() {
    // Array of my family 
    var humanName = ["Troy", "Beth", "Gabby", "Owen", "Evan"];
    
    document.write("My Family = ");
    
    // Loop through the humanName array
    for (var i = 0; i < humanName.length; i++) {
      document.write(humanName[i]);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your desired output?  Do you want the textbox to have inside of it the following:  My Family = Troy Beth Gabby Owen Evan

Comment: The js file is linked to the HTML and what happens when I click the button is the correct data gets output to a another html page rather than to the textbox.  My desired output will just be the names of my family and I will remove the "My Family = " and add commas, but that is stuff I can do afterwards.  so, I just need to have the names go into the textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

**HTML:**

```
<label for="fName">First Name </label>
<input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" />

<p>

<input type="button" value="JS Test" name="button1" onclick="writeHumanName()" />
```

**JS:**

```
function writeHumanName() {
  // Array of my family 
  var humanName = ["Troy", "Beth", "Gabby", "Owen", "Evan"];

  var myString = ("My Family = ");

  // Loop through the humanName array
  for (var i = 0; i < humanName.length; i++) {
    myString += (humanName[i]) + ", ";
  }

  document.getElementById('fName').value = myString;

}
```

**A working codepen:**  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waLLXO

Comment: No, that didn't do it.  It did prevent the text from going into another html page, but nothing went into the textbox either.

Comment: @tmwill0422 Sorry I fixed it

Comment: Progress!  Ok, so the data is now showing up in the textbox, however it is showing up on pageload...prior to the button being click?

Comment: @tmwill0422 in your HTML, the onclick="writeHumanName(this.form)" should just be onclick="writeHumanName()"   and check out the link I provided for a working example

Comment: I made those changes... copied your code.. and it is still populating the textbox on pageload rather than on button click... i tried a couple different browsers just to make sure it wasn't that.

Comment: Did you look at my example?  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waLLXO it's not preloading anything there.  If you have other code you are using, can you post that too?

Comment: You were right.  I was preloading that in another area of that page that was then auto populating it into the text box too.  Thank you very much.  I appreciate all your help.  It's nice that you guys are here to help people like me.  thanks again

Comment: @tmwill0422 Thanks tmwill.  Would you mind selecting one of the answers as correct?  :)

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/ebkd7sp4/8/

HTML:

```
<label for="fName">First Name </label>
<input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" />
<input type="button" value="JS Test" name="button1" onclick="writeHumanName()" />
```

JS:

```
function writeHumanName() {
  // Array of my family 
  var humanName = ["Troy", "Beth", "Gabby", "Owen", "Evan"];

  var text = "My Family = " + humanName.join(", ");

  document.getElementById("fName").value = text  
}
```

No need to pass anything into your function.  You can use the `join()` command to avoid the loop.  Use `document.getElementById("fName").value` to manipulate the text in your textbox.

Comment: This is pre-populating the textbox with the correct data... so, before I click the button the data is there... i tried in a couple different browsers

Comment: Something else has be calling that function.  Can you search your html and js for `writeHumanName()`

Comment: That's exactly what it was!!  Thank you to abaldwin99 and user3089840.  I really appreciate your help.  It's nice that you guys are here to help people like me.  I really do appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the js file(s) in your index page?

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello world</title>

  <!-- scripts -->
  <script src="js/file1.js"></script> <!-- include files -->
  <script src="js/file2.js"></script>       
</head>
```

Edit: It seems you're calling your function from html like so:

```
writeHumanName(this.form);
```

`this` will be the window object; you need to grab the div from the DOM and process it in JS...

```
function writeHumanName() {

    // Array of my family 
    var humanName = ["Troy", "Beth", "Gabby", "Owen", "Evan"],
        val = document.getElementById('fName').value;

    console.log("My Family = " + val);

    // Loop through the humanName array
    for (var i = 0; i < humanName.length; i++) {
        console.log(humanName[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes sir, I did.  With the code above, when I click the button it actually opens another page and prints the text "My Family = etc, etc..."  I know it's doing that because I have the document.write in there... I played with it most of the day trying to get it into the text box and I know the document.write is not the write code for this... but I went back to it because it at least outputted the correct data until I could get some help.